# Repeated column in mapping for entity, oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I am trying to do a one-to-many relationship between two tables. I have a table called users that has many user_history entries. I defined these tables in mysql and I generated the entities with intellij hibrernate support. The problem is that when i want to insert something in the databse I am receiving the following error *Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.UserHistoryEntity*

User:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.UsersEntity" table="users" schema="" catalog="protein_tracker">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" sql-type="varchar" length="45" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="total">
            <column name="total" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="goal">
            <column name="goal" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <set name="userHistoriesById" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="id_user" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="com.UserHistoryEntity"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserHistory:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.UserHistoryEntity" table="user_history" schema="" catalog="protein_tracker">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </id>
        <property name="entryDate">
            <column name="entry_date" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="entry">
            <column name="entry" sql-type="varchar" length="45" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="idUser">
            <column name="id_user" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="usersByIdUser" class="com.UsersEntity">
            <column name="id_user" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mark your `Many-To-One` mapping for usersByIdUser to insertable = false and updatable = false.  This allows the relationship to only be managed by a single property, `idUser` that you have mapped.